# strace detects calls to sendto, but GDB not detecting the function call

Tags: gdb, strace

I was analysing a multi-threaded process using strace and gdb.
On one of the pid I used the below command to analyse:

```
strace -tt -T -p 824722 2>&1 | grep -v "FUTEX"
```

The output showed that continuous calls to 'sendto' were being made. However when I attached gdb to the process, set breakpoint on 'sendto' and set the condition with respect to the thread ID(condition 1 $_thread==tid), I was surprised to see that gdb didn't find any 'sendto' function call.

What might be the reason behind gdb not detecting the function call? I have the source code also, but it will be easier for me if gdb/strace can tell me the exact line which led to 'sendto' call.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for a very long time with this. Finally I got the solution in the [comment section here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40344487/5701173).

So basically, instead of breakpoint, when I used 'catch syscall sendto', only then was gdb able to detect the 'sendto' call.